# MySQL. Поиск по нескольким совпадениям в строке

Tags: mysql

Допустим в поиск ввели запрос `samsung 10`, как по нему найти в запись типа `samsung 9/10`, при этом игнорируя `samsung 9`. Сейчас поиск разбивает запрос по пробелам, ищет по `samsung` и `10` и выдаёт все два варианта.

Comment: Просто заменить пробелы на знаки процента, добавить проценты в начале и конце - и готов паттерн для LIKE.

Comment: @Akina, а возможно добавить условие, чтобы между словами/цифрами было не более 3-4 символов, включая пробел? Иначе, под условие может попасть число из артикула, которое дописывается в конце строки.

Comment: Кто мешает? `.{,4}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверять, чтобы строка содержала **каждую** из искомых подстрок

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM mytable
WHERE
  INSTR(name, 'samsung') > 0 AND
  INSTR(name, '10') > 0
```